# Cannot use my models in sequelize typescript

Tags: typescript, postgresql, web, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to initialise my 'User' model in sequelize:

```
import { User } from "./models/User";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

private async connectToPostgreSQL() {
this.sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: this.POSTGRES_DB,
  username: this.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: this.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  host: this.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: this.POSTGRES_PORT,
  dialect: "postgres",
  models: [User]
});
```

But im always get an error:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 4, '(options?: Options | undefined): Sequelize', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ database: string; username: string; password: string; host: string; port: number; dialect: "postgres"; models: any[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'models' does not exist in type 'Options'.
> Overload 2 of 4, '(uri: string, options?: Options | undefined): Sequelize', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ database: string; username: string; password: string; host: string; port: number; dialect: string; models: any[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2769

What i can do to add my custom modal into serialize?

Versions:

```
"sequelize": "^6.34.0",
"sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Sequelize class from `sequelize-typescript`. Those parameters in that order are from the `sequelize-typescript` module.

```js
//import { Sequelize } from "sequelize"; //< Delete this
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize-typescript"; //< Add this
```